# Unity 2D on 10.04?

Tags: unity, 10.04

Why is there no Unity support for Lucid Lynx?

The newer versions of Ubuntu are too buggy  - the LTS version is well supported.

Why does Canonical not work on any new features as Unity for this current LTS release?

Answer (score 5):

Updates for old distributions are generally limited to security fixes rather than new features.  The long term support releases are really intended for people who value stability over features, and replacing core components of the desktop runs counter to that.

As Unity-2D did not exist at the time Ubuntu 10.04 was released, you shouldn't expect to see it pushed as an update.  If you want to try and get it running on that release, you will either need to compile it yourself or find someone who has done so for you and set up a PPA.

Answer (score 0):

10.04 has come and gone. 12.04 is what their aiming for for Unity. The goal is to move forward, not backward.

Comment: and you could try unity on lucid a while ago anyway.google and see what you can come up with.they have since moved on quite a bit..as nice as 10.04 was..and it was...